# groupby and stats on lists

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
'Location'    'Dir' 'Set'     'H1'    'H2'
0   Chicago     H1     4    *LIST*  *LIST*
1   Houston     H2     4    *LIST*  *LIST*
2   Los Angeles H2     4    *LIST*  *LIST*
3   Boston      H1     0    *LIST*  *LIST*
4   NYC         H2     0    *LIST*  *LIST*
5   Seattle     H1     0    *LIST*  *LIST*
```

All list items are NNx1 lists.

What I would like is to obtain the mean (NNx1 again) of each set, being dependent on the 'Dir' value.

For example, for Set 4, I would want he mean of Chicago H1, Houston H2, and Los Angeles H2. In addition, I would like the mean +/- sigma as well.

For example, assuming:

Chicago H1 is `[4,8,10]`

Houston H2 is `[8,4,12]`

Los Angeles H2 `[6,9,5]`

My mean would be `[6,7,9]`

I thought the .groupby method would be useful but I don't know how to put the conditionality on the 'Dir' column, as well as asking for the average of lists.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the element-wise mean of your filtered groups in the manner I show below. A few intermediate steps are necessary (reshaping data and converting lists to numpy arrays), but the steps should yield the lists (or arrays) of means that you want.

```
# melt H1 and H2 columns into key-value columns
# this will make it easier to select either the H1 or H2 list
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Location', 'Set', 'Dir'], \
value_vars=['H1', 'H2'], var_name="Target_Dir", value_name="Values")

# convert lists to numpy arrays
# in order to be able to specify the axis for the mean calculation
df.Values = df.Values.apply(np.array)

# filter df to your target Dirs, group by Set
# and calculate element-wise means
df[df['Dir'] == df['Target_Dir']].groupby('Set')['Values'].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x, axis=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['Chicago','Houston','Los Angeles','Boston','NYC','Seattle'],
                  'Dir':      ['H1','H2','H2','H1','H2','H1'],
                  'Set':      [4,4,4,0,0,0],
                  'SetCopy':  [4,4,4,0,0,0]})
mean = x.groupby(['Set','Dir']).mean()
sd = x.groupby(['Set','Dir']).std()
```

**Edit based on comments:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

x = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['Chicago','Houston','Los Angeles','Boston','NYC','Seattle'],
                  'Dir':      ['H1','H2','H2','H1','H2','H1'],
                  'Set':      [4,4,4,0,0,0],
                  'H1':       [[4,8,10],[8,4,12],[6,9,5],[6,7,9],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]})

mean = x.groupby(['Set','Dir']).H1.apply(
    lambda x: list(x)).apply(
    lambda x: np.mean(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))))

sd = x.groupby(['Set','Dir']).H1.apply(
    lambda x: list(x)).apply(
    lambda x: np.std(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))))
```

Comment: This is what I thought would do the drill...

but this actually doesn't do any good because assumming

Chicago H1 is [4,8,10]
Houston H2 is [8,4,12]
Los Angeles H2 [6,9,5]

My mean would be [6,7,9]

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, you also added the additional sample inputs after I answered so it's hard to know what you are looking for :)

Comment: I still don't understand how you are getting to that mean from the inputs.  If you are taking means by each unique `set` and `dir` grouping, wouldn't Set 4, H1 be simply (4+8+10) / 3 ? (ignoring the locations after LA, since they are not provided)